# Enqueue apt operation

Tags: linux, apt

Can I enqueue e.g. `apt-get install somepackage`?

For instance during an upgrade, I remember that I need to install htop and `apt-get install htop` complains about a lock. Then, it would be nice if I could write `apt-get --enqueue install htop` or something.

Comment: Most linux console applications I've used allow you type the next command(s) while the current one is still running. So don't open a new console, try typing the command you want into the current one and press enter to execute it when the current one is finished. Or, if you can't remember the syntax type it into another one and then copy-paste it into the running one before pressing enter.

Comment: You can use the `batch` command to have the command execute when the system gets idle (which would hopefully happen once the upgrade is finished). But @mokubai's solution is simpler.

Comment: Let us say that I've started the upgrade in terminal A and remember that I want to install jed. Now, I cannot install it in terminal B until the upgrade is finished in terminal A and my brain needs to remember that I want to do something when the upgrade is finished. That is my basic problem.